# Golang for loop wont stop

Tags: go

So I am starting to learn the Go Programming Language and was hoping someone might be able to clarify why I'm getting the results I'm getting. I'm trying to have the program read input from the user and display it back until the user only enters the newline character. 
package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "bufio"
    "strings"
)

func main(){

    inputBuff := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    line,_ := inputBuff.ReadString('\n')

    for  (!strings.EqualFold(line,"\n")){
        line,err := inputBuff.ReadString('\n')
        if err!=nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(line)
        fmt.Println(!strings.EqualFold(line,"\n"))
    }

}
```

I am trying to read in full strings at a time so i thought the bufio would be better the using Scan. I added the last print to show that the method is returning false but the loop continues to execute. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the `line` inside the loop is not the same `line` you initiated for the check. FTFY:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "bufio"
    "strings"
)

func main(){

    inputBuff := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    line,_ := inputBuff.ReadString('\n')
    var err error
    for  (!strings.EqualFold(line,"\n")){
        line,err = inputBuff.ReadString('\n')
        if err!=nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(line)
        fmt.Println(!strings.EqualFold(line,"\n"))
    }
```

You used the `:=` assignment operator inside the loop, as in `line, err := ....`. 
This makes Go create a new symbol inside the the for loop with the name `line`. But the for's check is outside the inner scope of the loop code block. So it refers to the old `line` that was initiated outside the loop.

Changing the operator inside the loop to `=` doesn't create a new variable, but also doesn't init `err`, so I defined it beforehand too. `err` can be declared inside the loop but that's redundant.

Comment: Just to mention, this is because loops (and blocks such as `if` or `switch`) create a scope in Go. So when yo declare a variable inside that scope, you're shadowing the outer variable.

Comment: yeah I thought that was obvious but you're right, it's worth mentioning :)

Comment: Could you explain how they are different? I thought the line would be the same as its initialized outside the loop.

Comment: Then how does the change fix this issue?

Comment: @DavidFirestone I've updated my answer, I hope it better explains it now.

Comment: It does thank you. This was my first time posting a question. Is there anything I can do to like up vote or something?